# jQuery - get all links where text=mytext

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I want to select all a elements that have text=mytext. I looking for something like that:

```
$('.scroll').find("a[text=" + "mytext" + "]").css('background-color', 'green');
```

Why this is not working?

**edit:**

```
<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow</a>
```

text=stackoverflow

Comment: do you mean tag content with 'text'?

Comment: what do you mean by `text` the content of the element

Comment: Yes, I mean the contents of the tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in that case

```
$('.scroll a').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'mytext'
}).css('background-color', 'green');
```

`:contains()` does not suit your case because it does not test for equality

Answer (score 2):

Use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('.scroll').find("a:contains('mytext')").css('background-color', 'green');
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$('.scroll').find("a:contains('mytext')").css('background-color', 'green');
```